# Websockets with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm having trouble trying to play with websockets, so I made a toy echo server and tried to send requests directly to it from the browser console.  I can send a message from the browser to the server, and the server is recieving it properly, but it's not sending the echo back.  Here is the server code and browser console code I'm running as a little test:

server.js

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
      connection.sendUTF("message test");
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

firefox console input:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080', 'echo-protocol');
// undefined
// GET http://localhost:8080/
connection.onmessage = function(mess) {console.log(mess.data);};
// function connection.onmessage()
connection.send("hello");
// undefined
```

command prompt input and output:

```
> node server.js
Fri Oct 09 2015 22:57:18 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) Server is listening on port 8080
Fri Oct 09 2015 22:57:21 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) Connection accepted.
Received Message: hello
```

I did `npm install websocket` before making the toy server, so if the problem lies in the websocket library I'm using, that's the one

My server clearly gets to at least line 22 since it prints out the message sent to it from the browser, but the browser console doesnt show any response when the message is supposedly sent back on the next line with the sendUTF function.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is my browser silently dropping the response?

Comment: Edit: it works on Chrome, but not Firefox.  I'll update if I find an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I really hope it's this easy (for your sake)...

In the Firefox Browser Console, on the "Logging" drop-down, click "Log". Your exact code seemed to fail on my machine in Firefox, yet it worked in Chrome. Then I found that option in the Firefox console and I saw your `message test` output.